# Optimize code sequence on Java Card

Tags: java, optimization, javacard

I'm trying to implement an BCH code correction on a Java Card . I already implemented the `encode` function and now I'm working on decoding the input.My results seems correct but the time spent on `decode` function is very large.I figured out that the sequence of code given below is most time consumption.

```
    Util.arrayCopy(data, OFFSET_START, transientMemory, OFFSET_START,LENGTH);
    short i, j, u, q, t2, count = 0, syn_error = 0;
    t2 = (short) (2 * T);
    for (i = 1; i <= t2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
            if (transientMemory[j] != 0)
            {
                short t = (short)(i*j);
                if(t < 0) // (i*j > 32767 )
                {
                    t &= (short)0x7FFF;
                    t += 64;  // hack because n is always 511
                }
                t %= n;
                s[i] ^= ALPHA_TO[t]; // stored in EEPROM
            }   
        if (s[i] != 0)
            syn_error = 1; 
        s[i] = (short) INDEX_OF[s[i]]; //stored in EEPROM

   }
   Util.arrayCopy(transientMemory, OFFSET_START, data, OFFSET_START,LENGTH);
   ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CORRECT_LENGTH_00); // for stopping the program
```

I preallocated two buffers of RAM `transientMemory` for `byte[]` and `temp_ram` for `short[]` but the time is seems that the execution time is still large ( `370` s ) .The value of `t2` in this case is `104` and the value of `LENGTH` is `386`. Is any way I could make this piece of code to work better

Comment: This doesn't contain a specific question and working code and is therefore on topic on http://codereview.stackexchange.com . You can do something like `syn_error ^= s[i]` as a hint. The fewer branching instructions the better. Minimizing the number of variables (registers) also helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some strength reduction. Multiplication and division on some low end CPU is costly, so I'd replace

```
short t = (short)(i*j);
```

by `t += i` after declaring it as `short t = 0` before the inner loop.

If I understand this block correctly

```
if(t < 0) // (i*j > 32767 )
{
    t &= (short)0x7FFF;
    t += 64;  // hack because n is always 511
}
t %= n;
```

it does the same as `t %= 511` would do if `t` was an `int`. As `t` must fit in an unsigned short, assuming ordinary Java you could write

```
t += (t & 511) + ((t >>> 9) & 63);
if (t >= 511) t -= 511;
```

No idea how to translate it to what you need as I don't know how to express a shift of a `short` (in ordinary Java, the shift operand gets promoted to an `int`). It might work the way I wrote it...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to somehow optimize my code by storing some variables in RAM instead of EEPROM.Here is the updated code

```
    byte[] transientMemory = p_Memory.geByteRam();
    short[] temp_ram = p_Memory.getShortRam();
    short index = 0;
    for(; index < n ; index++)
        temp_ram[index]=ALPHA_TO[index];
    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(data, OFFSET_START, transientMemory, OFFSET_START,LENGTH);
    short i, j, u, q, t2, count = 0, syn_error = 0,s_local=0;
    t2 = (short) (2 * T);
    for (i = 1; i <= t2; i++)
    {
        s_local = s[i];
        for (j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++)
            if (transientMemory[j] != 0)
            {
                short t = (short)(i*j);
                if(t < 0) // (i*j > 32767 )
                {
                    t &= (short)0x7FFF;
                    t += 64;  // hack because n is always 511
                }
                t %= n;
                s_local ^= temp_ram[t]; 
            }   
        if (s_local != 0)
            syn_error = 1; 
        s[i] = (short) INDEX_OF[s_local];
   }
    for(; index < n ; index++)
        ALPHA_TO[index]=temp_ram[index];
```

Now the execution time seems to be close to `45s`.